# Small Caps for Gnuplot Labels

Tags: pdf, gnuplot, smallcaps

I'm looking for a command or something equivalent to draw labels in Gnuplot with small caps, like using `\texsc{Mylabel}` in LaTeX. Is there any chance to do so without using latex as terminal? I prefer to generate PDF directly.

Comment: A not robust workaround is to use something like `set label "{/:=16 M}YLABEL" font ",12"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a workaround using the same strategy used by [@mjp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6235596/mjp) and [@theozh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7295599/theozh) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54174759/11369382).

```
# Implements a 'textsc' function like in (La)TeX.
# Based on original answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54174759/11369382

reset
set encoding utf8 # mandatory

LCases="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
SCases="ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ"

toscchr(c)= c eq ""  ?  ""  :  substr( SCases.c, strstrt(LCases.c, c), strstrt(LCases.c, c) )

texsc(s) = strlen(s) <= 1 ? toscchr(s) : texsc(s[1:strlen(s)/2]).texsc(s[(strlen(s)/2)+1:strlen(s)])

Mylabel = "The Quick Brown Fox jumps over the Lazy Dog"

position = "at graph 0.2,0.60"

set label Mylabel        @position offset 0, 0
set label texsc(Mylabel) @position offset 0,-1

plot x w p pt -1 not
```

Result

[image: result]